# Apache wrong localhost location

Tags: apache, ubuntu, permissions, localhost, http-status-code-403

After so many times trying and receiving 403 Forbidden error:

```
http://localhost/

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I finally checked the `apachectl -S` and realized that the location of local host folder is not set correctly:

```
$ apachectl -S

Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

It clearly says that my localhost folder is /var/www while my setting is something else:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/mynewsite.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/user/www

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
ServerName localhost
```

For the file permission:

```
$ ls -la /home/user/

total 3097944
drwx------  9 user user          4096 Jan  3 19:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 45 user user          4096 Jan  3 20:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 48 user www-data       4096 Jan  3 20:30 www
```

Apache restart has no problem too:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [ OK ]
```

I am wondering what is wrong?

Comment: Did you try `chmod a+x /home/user`? I don't think www-data will be able to access `/home/user/www/` if `/home/user/` cannot be accessed?

Comment: thank you very much. that is the exact problem. now solved. but any way to show `user` in line `User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used` so not need to change permission?

Comment: You're welcome, I've posted my comment as answer (please accept). I'm not sure what exactly you mean with your new question, go ahead and open a new Stackoverflow question for that one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do a `chmod a+x /home/user/`, since www-data will not be able to access `/home/user/www/` if `/home/user/` cannot be accessed.